# Library not loaded: @rpath/Electron Framework.framework/Electron Framework

Tags: electron

When I want to run my electron app on MacOS Sonoma, I get the following error. The build works just fine, only the dev and start script experience this problem. I get this error when creating a new project with `pnpm create @quick-start/electron` and immediately trying to run it (after installing the dependencies).

```
dyld[4469]: Library not loaded: @rpath/Electron Framework.framework/Electron Framework
  Referenced from: <4C4C445B-5555-3144-A19E-53F4BE098A48> /Users/user/project/node_modules/.pnpm/electron@28.1.0/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron
  Reason: tried: '/Users/user/project/node_modules/.pnpm/electron@28.1.0/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Electron Framework' (no such file), '/Users/user/project/node_modules/.pnpm/electron@28.1.0/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Electron Framework' (no such file)
```

I already tried reinstalling all packages and also upgrading them to their latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove your package managers' cache,
I tried https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/40345 and it worked
as `philjones88` said, there might be errored version of electron

```
npm cache clean --force
yarn cache clean --force
pnpm store prune
```